# Override curl config file option in curl command

Tags: curl, file-upload, overriding, config

**Scenario** - I've a couple of webAPIs to be invoked using curl command. For common config (i.e. authentication headers and some request headers) we use a config file and refer it in the curl command. Most of webAPIs are json based now recently we added a new curl command execution which need to upload a file (via form-post).

> This new webAPI call requires **header "Content-Type:
>   multipart/form-data"** which is different from our common setting in the
>   curl config file (header "Content-Type: application/json"). If we
>   remove the header for content-type a lot of curl commands will need
>   edits. So instead we opted to keep the config file intact and instead
>   we used those config file options directly in the new file upload curl
>   command (i.e. no config file).

I just wanted to know if this the only way or can I somehow override the curl config file option by specifying it in the curl command. I believe this to be a common scenario (i.e. like in HTML we use css for styling but we can override style by specifying the same attribute directly within the html element).